# How to access Android's "dynamicFeatures" property from a custom Gradle plugin in buildSrc

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, dynamic-feature-module

In my project, I'd like to generate a class that contains information about my dynamic features. Dynamic features are added this way:

```
// In the base module’s build.gradle file.
android {
    ...
    // Specifies dynamic feature modules that have a dependency on
    // this base module.
    dynamicFeatures = [":dynamic_feature", ":dynamic_feature2"]
}
```

*Source: https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/at-install-delivery#base_feature_relationship*

I've been searching for solutions since a few days now, and I didn't find much. Currently, my plugin looks like this:

```
class MyPlugin : Plugin<Project> {

    override fun apply(project: Project) {
        if (project == rootProject) {
            throw Exception("This plugin cannot be applied to root project")
        }

        val parent = project.parent ?: throw Exception("Parent of project cannot be null")

        val extension = project.extensions.getByName("android") as BaseAppModuleExtension?
            ?: throw Exception("Android extension cannot be null")

        extension.dynamicFeatures
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, extension.dynamicFeatures is empty even if my plugin is applied to the build.gradle file having dynamic features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's empty, because you are trying to get extension value at the gradle lifecycle configuration stage, all gradle properties have not configured yet.

Use `afterEvaluate` closure. In this block `dynamicFeatures` has already configured and not empty.

```
project.afterEvaluate {
    val extension = project.extensions.getByType(BaseAppModuleExtension::class.java)
        ?: throw Exception("Android extension cannot be null")
    extension.dynamicFeatures
}
```